# How to unite two Observables?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have two `IObservable<bool>` ( canEdit1 and canEdit2 ), how can I unite them?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var canEdit1 = InerrProperty1.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Property1, x => x,
                (prop1, x) => prop1 != null &&  x != null);
var canEdit2 = InerrProperty2.WhenAnyValue(x=> x.Property1, x=>x.Property2, 
    (prop1,prop2) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop2));
```

Comment: What do you mean "unite" ? Can you provide few examples of what should happen with different values in different sequence?

Comment: @HereticMonkey This seems to be a ReactiveUI question. Can't use the RxJS solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) functionality. It should look something like this:

```
var merged = canEdit1.Merge(canEdit2);
```

You can later subscribe to it, or do additional operators on it.

Answer (score 0):

With the `system.reactive` library, there are multiple ways for [combining](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining) observables. Has explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064570/does-net-reactive-extensions-framework-rx-takes-topological-order-into-consid), none implements a topological ordered query resolution. In a cases like diamond dependency graph, none of them will avoid intermediate/incoherent states.

[image: diamond dependency graph: A -> Input, B -> Input, Output -> A, Output ->B]

[Storm.Net](https://github.com/StormDotNet/Storm.NET) (Simple Topologically Ordered Reactive Model) his an attempt to provide a data model that propagates update in a topological order.